# min of all columns of the dataframe in a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, min

I want to find the min value of every row of a dataframe restricting to only few columns. 
For example: consider a dataframe of size 10*100. I want the min of middle 5 rows and this becomes of size 10*5.

I know to find the min using df.min(axis=0) but i dont know how to restrict the number of columns. Thanks for the help.

I use pandas lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by selecting the slice of columns you are interested in and applying `DataFrame.min()` to only that selection:

```py
df.iloc[:, start:end].min(axis=0)
```

If you want these to be the middle 5, simply find the integer indices which correspond to the start and end of that range:

```py
start = int(n_columns/2 - 2.5)
end = start + 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the 'pciunkiewicz's logic:

First you should select the columns that you desire. You can use the functions: `.loc[..]` or `.iloc[..]`.

The first one you can use the names of the columns. When it takes 2 arguments, the first one is the row's index. The second is the columns.

```
df.loc[[rows], [columns]] # The filter data should be inside the brakets.
df.loc[:, [columns]] # This will consider all rows.
```

You can also use `.iloc`. In this case, you have to use integers to locate the data. So you don't have to know the name of the columns, but their position.